# reading file from .htaccess secure directory

Tags: file, security, .htaccess, directory

I have some problems with my `.htaccess`, which work great but I really don't know how read file in the secure directory, and then how I can embed them, like an image in my webpage.

I tried with `readfile()`, but it shows just the image, and I can't embed it.

Comment: Somewhat confused about what you are asking. Are you asking how to embed an image on a webpage (`<img src="/some/url.png" />`), where `/some/url.png` actually internaly rewrites to `/some/secure/url.png`? If so: Please include your `.htaccess` and any other attempts you made to solve this problem.

Comment: You most likely want to implement a proxy php-script, that checks permissions for example and then outputs the image? Then create a php-file that sets the content-type via `header` and then output the image. Then embed the image by referring to the proxy php script (`<img src="proxy.php?file=some_protected_image">`).